# Axios put return undefined [React JS + Axios]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hi all im doing an axios put to update my data. However im getting an undefined response. Thank you in advance

function that call the Axios:

```
export function exUpdateMovie(movie) {
 
  Axios.put(baseURL + "/api/update", {
    movieName: movie.movieName,
    movieReview: movie.movieReview,
    id: movie.id,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // console.log(response);
      return response;
    })

    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    });
}
```

function in app.js that calls the exUpdateMovie(movie) function:

```
const handleUpdateMovie = (movie) => {
    console.log("UpdateMovie Passed!");

    try {
      const res = exUpdateMovie(movie);   
      alert(res?.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Output when I alert my response is:
**undefined**

SETTLE:

- need to add async and await at the `handleUpdateMovie`
- need to return the Axios by doing `return Axios.put()`

Cheers mate for helping me. Thanks alot

Comment: when I just return `response` from `exUpdateMovie`. Its still undefined

Comment: `exUpdateMovie` _doesn't_ return anything. You completely ignore the promise chain created by `Axios.put`. Also you don't `await` it or use `.then` in the caller, so even if you _did_ return the correct promise you'd be receiving the promise object (which also has no `data` property).

Comment: so how I do go about this problem?

Comment: _Do_ return a promise from `exUpdateMovie`? Then _do_ `await` it or use `.then` in `handleUpdateMovie`?

Comment: ok I added the async and await in `handleUpdateMovie`. but how to I return a promise from `exUpdateMovie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `exUpdateMovie` doesn't return anything.  Return the Promise:

```
export function exUpdateMovie(movie) {

  return Axios.put(/* all your Axios code */);

}
```

Then when consuming the result, treat it as a Promise:

```
exUpdateMovie(movie).then(res => {
  alert(res?.data);
});
```

Comment: thanks man. I just realised I didnt return the Axios. My bad but cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes because your api call is returning a promise where you need to wait until the promise execution completes so make your function async and wrap the API call with await.

```
export async function exUpdateMovie(movie) {
  const result = await  Axios.put(baseURL + "/api/update", {
    movieName: movie.movieName,
    movieReview: movie.movieReview,
    id: movie.id,
  })
    return result
}

const handleUpdateMovie = async (movie) => {
    console.log("UpdateMovie Passed!");

    try {
      const res = await exUpdateMovie(movie);   
      alert(res?.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: the main function must return something in order to receive the data in the handler function.

Comment: `still doesn't return anything though...` then how do I return something??

Comment: @NazriAMZ please check I've updated my answer. please try to use async and await instead of callbacks.